# SSRS align columns of chart to table columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have a table in my SSRS report showing several values, followed by a column chart in the last row. I require each chart column to be directly under its respective column. Currently, the columns are all stacked next to each other, and I'm unable to position them on the chart manually. Is there a way this can be done?

Example:

```
      A  B  C
      1  3  1
      1  1  1
      1  2  1
      1  2  1
Total 4  8  4

         | 
      |  |  | --This is how I want it to appear

         |
        |||   --This is how it currently appears
```

I want to be able to spread out the columns manually so that I can place each column under its respective table column.

Comment: Have you considered creating the columns all in the same table or tablix?

Comment: Have you tried adding a new row under the total row and adding a Data Bar to each of those cells?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the answers to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658791/how-do-i-align-the-width-of-chart-with-the-width-of-tablix-in-ssrs-2008-r2-or/22674352#22674352

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to put the bar under the table, but I had a similar problem where I needed to get the bars at the top of my table.

From SSRS 2008R2 in the matrix column group you have the possibility to add a column chart.

You can find the step by step tutorial to this done on the technet site at this link

[How to: Display the Same Data on a Matrix and a Chart (Reporting Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627508%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)